# JavaScript to create multiple URLs replacing one part of the URL in every iteration, but maintaining the rest of it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, url, url-rewriting

I've been trying multiple codes but I cannot seem to crack it.

1. I have a base URL that directs to the "About" page in every BMC journal page
   https://biomedcentral.com/about
2. I want to target the "About" pages of ALL BMC journals in my list

example 1: BMC Primary Care = https://**bmcprimcare**.biomedcentral.com/about

example 2: BMC Neuroscience = https://**bmcneurosci**.biomedcentral.com/about

As you can see, each journal page differs in its initial code (above in bold).

I need a JavaScript code that will produce the same base URL multiple times, but each time with a different journal code. The goal is to target the "About" pages from ALL journals on my list.

I would so appreciate the help!!

Comment: Please provide an expected output and code sample of your attempt to solve this problem. You mention you're trying to "target" the "about" page, but what are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Template literals (`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const baseURL = 'https://biomedcentral.com/about';

const journalCodeArr = ['bmcprimcare', 'bmcneurosci'];

const result = journalCodeArr.map((journalCode) => {
    const splitBaseURL = baseURL.split('//');
  return `${splitBaseURL[0]}//${journalCode}.${splitBaseURL[1]}`
});

console.log(result);
```